# How to calculate speed with Core Location?

Tags: iphone, gps, core-location, accelerometer, gyroscope

How can I calculate speed using Core Location? I would like to use GPS but even Accelerometer and Gyroscope if it's possible.

GPS + Accelerometer + Gyroscope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreLocation delivers speed data directly. This is apparently more accurate than position readings.

Comment: Do you have a source for this info? In the docs for CLLocation.speed it says: "Because the actual speed can change many times between the delivery of subsequent location events, you should use this property for informational purposes only." Which makes it sounds less accurate to me??

Comment: @Lewis42: No, it just means you can't integrate velocity to track the position.